# Yocto build immediately failed

Tags: yocto

I have a PC that usually used for Yocto image building. Now I need to add ROS2 packages to the same image. After all it's turned out the disk is full so I've connected a SSD external disk to build the image on it. I did the same steps as before, run the same command etc. but after the build starts if crashed at the first package. I've reinstalled all the sources from zero, I've deleted `tmp` and `ssstate-cache` but nothing help. I don't understand what this error says.

[This is error trace log](https://justpaste.it/3o1an)

As I see Yocto fail to write something into ssstate-cache/61, I don't really know what that is. A user has read/write permissions.

**The build system:** Ubuntu 20.04

**Yocto version:** zeus

Comment: try disabling sstate-cache.

Comment: Ok, do you know how can I do that? This project just lacks normal documentation.

Comment: https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Enable_sstate_cache

Comment: I am not sure what's happening, but I suspect env issues, e.g. permissions, filesystem, etc.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk, the link is about enabling, there is nothing about disabling the feature. As for permissions, I've checked that twice, everything is ok

Comment: you just need to do the opposite :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the linked error log, the relevant part is:

```
SignatureGeneratorOEBasicHash.dump_sigtask(fn='/media/sw/Samsung/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/texinfo-dummy-native/texinfo-dummy-native.bb', task='do_fetch', stampbase='/media/sw/Samsung/yocto/build-xwayland/sstate-cache/61/sstate:texinfo-dummy-native::1.0:r0::3:610ed4b8e8bf78bbcd4a667b6645a0276f5c8bfce5de4822923850d44d032bbe_fetch.tgz.siginfo', runtime='customfile:/media/sw/Samsung/yocto/build-xwayland/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/texinfo-dummy-native/1.0-r0'):
                 os.chmod(tmpfile, 0o664)
    >            os.rename(tmpfile, sigfile)
             except (OSError, IOError) as err:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/media/sw/Samsung/yocto/build-xwayland/sstate-cache/61/sigtask.twkjztl9' -> '/media/sw/Samsung/yocto/build-xwayland/sstate-cache/61/sstate:texinfo-dummy-native::1.0:r0::3:610ed4b8e8bf78bbcd4a667b6645a0276f5c8bfce5de4822923850d44d032bbe_fetch.tgz.siginfo'
```

It is likely that the new name is not valid for the target disk filesystem. Typically the `:` character is invalid on FAT/NTFS filesystems. Native Linux filesystems like Ext4, XFS and Btrfs will not have this limitation.

Comment: Looks like you're right. That was an external SSD disk with Windows FS. I've formatted that in Ext4 and that solved the issue. Thank you.